# Windows Phone 7 how do I remove "stuttering" when switching between pivot items

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

When switching to pivot items that load data, I'm experiencing stuttering when switching from one item to the other.   I've separated the data loads to a separate thread and that has helped, but I'm still experiencing some bad performance....Was wondering if you guys had any ideas....

Here's the pivot item

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <!--Pivot control-->
    <controls:Pivot Name="panCorals" Title="Corals" Foreground="#01487e" 
        SelectionChanged="panCorals_SelectionChanged">

        <controls:Pivot.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="PivotBackground.png"/>
        </controls:Pivot.Background>

        <!--Search Corals-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Search" Foreground="#01487e">

            <Grid>

                <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Name="SearchCoralsProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="466" 
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsSearchLoading}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsSearchLoading}" />

                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Name="txtSearchTerm" KeyDown="txtSearchTerm_KeyDown" />
                    <ListBox Name="lbSearchCorals" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchCorals}" 
                         SelectionChanged="lbSearchCorals_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding MainImageURI}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" />
                                    <StackPanel Width="311">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommonName}" Foreground="#112d42"  TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScientificName}" Foreground="#112d42" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

        </controls:PivotItem>


        <!--Top Corals-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Top" Foreground="#01487e" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

            <Grid>

                <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Name="TopCoralsProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="466" 
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsTopLoading}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsTopLoading}" />


                <ListBox Name="lbTopCorals" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding TopCorals}" SelectionChanged="lbTopCorals_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <Image Source="{Binding MainImageURI}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" />
                                <StackPanel Width="311">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommonName}" Foreground="#112d42"  TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScientificName}" Foreground="#112d42" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

                <StackPanel Margin="10,50,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbProgress"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>

        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--New Corals-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="New">
            <Grid>

                <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Name="NewCoralsProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="466" 
                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsNewLoading}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsNewLoading}" />

                <ListBox Name="lbNewCorals" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding NewCorals}" SelectionChanged="lbNewCorals_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <Image Source="{Binding MainImageURI}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" />
                                <StackPanel Width="311">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommonName}" Foreground="#112d42"  TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScientificName}" Foreground="#112d42" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>


    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind...

```
private void panCorals_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (panCorals.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:     //search corals

                break;
            case 1:         //top corals
                if (!App.vmCoral.IsTopDataLoaded)
                {
                    App.vmCoral.IsTopLoading = true;
                    if (App.HasConnectivity)
                    {
                        //get corals from web
                        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWorkTopCoralsWeb);

                        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
                        {
                            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //get saved corals from device
                        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWorkTopCoralsSaved);

                        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
                        {
                            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:         //new corals

                if (!App.vmCoral.IsNewDataLoaded)
                {
                    App.vmCoral.IsNewLoading = true;
                    if (App.HasConnectivity)
                    {
                        //get corals from web
                        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWorkNewCoralsWeb);

                        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
                        {
                            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //get saved corals from device
                        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWorkNewCoralsSaved);

                        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
                        {
                            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
            default:

                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with the code you posted per se.  Most likely what is happening is your background worker thread is completing while you are switching between pivot items, which is in turn updating the observable collections to which your lists are bound.  Also your lists contain images which, if you are binding to a URL on the web which requires the image to be downloaded, will also cause perf problems.

There are a couple things to check:

1. make sure you are using a virtualized stack panel if your lists are long (this is the default but make sure you haven't changed it anywhere).
2. consider using the LongListSelector control from the SL toolkit, it has better UI and data virtualization support than the default ListBox
3. check out the low profile image loader if you are binding your images to web urls ([http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)).
4. Enable the "EnableRedrawRegions" debug indicator in your App.xaml.cs.  Check that nothing is causing regions to be redrawn while you are switching pivot items (indicated by a section of the screen flashing different colors very quickly).  Consider using BitMapCache if they are.
5. If your async process is downloading a long list consider breaking the list up on the background thread and only dispatching them to the UI thread in small chunks with a small delay between each one.

Comment: Just wanted to mention and give you credit for the LongListSelector idea.  This seems to be the thing that really helped.

Answer (score 2):

One common situation that happens is that although you load data completely on a separate thread, after load is completed there are lot's of UI work for binding items to the ListBox.

One solution that I found times ago on the net (I actually lost the track of the link) is to add items to your ObservableCollection (in your case SearchCorals) one by one and with a bit of delay (let's say 50ms). (instead of adding them in bulk).

For doing this you can store your datasource on memory and use DispatcherTimer to run every 50ms and add items to SearchCorals one-by-one.

This solved my problem I hope it can help with yours.

Comment: the stuttering happens when I switch from the search pivot to the "top" pivot item.  The animation pauses, then the top page loads, then I get the loading animation, THEN the data loads.  I have to wait another few seconds once the stuttering is over.